# how to use object_recognition_kitchen(ORK)?

Tags: ros, ros-indigo, ecto, object-recognition-kitchen

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using Indigo+ubuntu14.04(32bit)

I am trying to make some experiment with [ORK（object recognition kitchen）](http://wg-perception.github.io/object_recognition_core/).

But I've had a lot of trouble.Here are my steps follow the tutorial of ORK:

First : `sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-ecto-*`

Second : `sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-ecto-*`

Third :  [database configuration](http://wg-perception.github.io/object_recognition_core/infrastructure/couch.html#object-recognition-core-db)

Last :  follow [Quick Guide](http://wg-perception.github.io/object_recognition_core/quickguide.html#quickguide)as belows:

①`rosrun object_recognition_core push.sh`②`source /opt/indigo/setup/ros.sh`③`roscore`④`roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch`⑤`rosrun object_recognition_capture orb_template -o my_textured_plane`

Then the KeyError hanppend：

[image: image description]

In another way,I try to built it from source,it's result like:

[image: image description]

I don't know how to deal with it,and my purpose is to recognise some specified objects and show its coordinates.

Please give me a guide or some advice, thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/228858/how-to-use-object_recognition_kitchen(ork)-?/) by [baogege](https://answers.ros.org/users/22605/baogege/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2016-03-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As i've done with my ros indigo, go to this link:
http://rememberthecmd.blogspot.in/2015/08/install-ork.html
after building the workspace, to run the ork follow:
http://wg-perception.github.io/ork_tutorials/tutorial02/tutorial.html
this worked in mine, wish u good luck.

---

Originally posted by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) with karma: 932 on 2016-06-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0